# How to create framework with other frameworks and library dependency?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know, there are so many same questions but I didn't get answer for my requirement.
First time I am creating framework. I have created test framework using Raywenderlich example. But my requirement is little bit different. I used so many different frameworks and also used SQLCipher in my project. Now, I want to convert this project into framework. I followed all the steps but the problem is occur when I am trying to build. Getting an error for SQLCypher because I didn’t add to my framework to avoid conflicts. Finally, I have added SQLCypher library to create build without error and it worked but now I am getting linker error when I am using that framework to test in testProject. I didn’t find any example with third parties. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

One solution is to change all method names of other frameworks or libs, but some lib is not open source.

Another solution is work for me which is to use cocoapods. But the user 
who wants to use your framework will be forced using cocoapods, depending iOS 8.0 or above, depending the same version of 3rd libs. I have nothing to do with this restriction.

Seems the best way is do not depend 3rd libs in a framework.

Comment: My issue is resolved. Now, we should add all dependencies. So, I have added all the frameworks which I used in my framework also added third party and then created framework. It is working fine and I also check with conflicts. Now, it won't occur.

Comment: @chaaruu Have you tested for this scene : Your framework A depends framework B, a project P depends A and B, there will be a symbol duplicated error when you try building.

Comment: Yes, I tested. after that only I continued. few months before Apple resolved this issue as per one senior :)

Comment: @chaaruu That's good news, I will try this way. Thanks for sharing :)